# How to view or transfer initial ethereum smart contract balance?

Tags: remix, tokens, ether, metamask

I created a new smart contract token with initial supply and deployed it via MetaMask. Then I added this token into MetaMask but token balance is Zero.

Now, My question is when we create a new contract then from where we get the initial balance for an address ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a token contract you define how many tokens there are initially. Furthermore you typically also define how the tokens can be distributed and who owns them - usually the original owner is either a crowdsale contract or the token contract creator.

So, without seeing your code (and especially how you deploy it - constructor arguments are often used for defining these things) it's impossible to know where to tokens are. If you simply create a simple token contract with initial balance nobody owns the tokens and therefore they can never be transferred anywhere. So remember to set someone as the token owner.